# How can I configure travis CI build to use a specific version of rubygems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, travis-ci

I have a `.travis.yml` file like this

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 1.8.7
  - 1.9.2
  - 1.9.3
gemfile:
  - gemfiles/rails23.gemfile
  - gemfiles/rails30.gemfile
  - gemfiles/rails32.gemfile
  - gemfiles/rails3x.gemfile
```

For the `gemfiles/rails23.gemfile` I would like to use a specific version of `rubygems` (in this case one that is prior to 2.0.0). How can I specify that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish it's not possible as stated by this [Closed Issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/68). I quote:

> "We use rubygems version that RVM provides and there are no plans to
>   change that."

Comment: Too sad that Travis-ci choose the rubygems thap RVM provides and not the one that is bundled with ruby.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to [downgrade the rubygems version](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/ruby/#Upgrading-RubyGems), just add the following to your `.travis.yml`

```
before_install:
  - gem update --system 2.0.0 
  - gem --version
```